# Run pre-commit conventional commit check on squash commit before merge into master only

Tags: python, version-control, gitlab-ci, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

I want to run the [commitizen](https://github.com/commitizen-tools/commitizen) (python implementation of conventional commit message enforcement) lint check (`cz check`) within my GitLab CI pipeline but **ONLY** on the squash commit that precedes a merge into master from a feature branch.

I can't get my head around how to do this. My understanding/assumption is as follows:

- This is only going to be possible if my merge strategy is merge commit (i.e. not fast forward) because I need there to be a commit that can fail (before the merge into master) so that the merge can then abort - if it was just 1 commit as per fast-forward strategy, it would be too late; the code would already be in master and then the pipeline would fail. Luckily, I am fine with this but I'm curious as to how you would solve for this with fast-forward.
- The squash commit runs on the feature branch which triggers a pipeline.
- If I fail the squash commit pipeline, GitLab CI will not proceed to the merge commit.

If my assumptions are correct, I would need to detect whether the commit a given pipeline is handling is a squash commit or not - but I can't figure out how to do this - there doesn't seem to be any *signal* from either gitlab or git that I could use in my pipeline.

In terms of implementation, I intend to add the [pre-commit hook provided by commitizen](https://github.com/commitizen-tools/commitizen#integrating-with-pre-commit) but I will use `stages: [manual]` and then within my pipeline, I'll run `pre-commit run --hook-stage manual [hookid]` as per [pre-commit docs](https://pre-commit.com/#confining-hooks-to-run-at-certain-stages).